# How to add a scroll view to an ios app

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

I have a tabbed application that I would like to have a scroll view on. I already have a few text fields and labels on that tab. The problem is, the keyboard hides some of the text fields. How would I add a vertical scroll to prevent that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish what you are looking for without a scrollview.

In you delegate method for you textfield, You can change the frame of the viewController's view.

something like

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;           
{
CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
newFrame.origin.y = - 40;  // move the view up to the point your textfield is visible
self.view.frame = newFrame;
}
```

Then in Set it back

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;  
{
 CGRect newFrame = self.view.frame;
 newFrame.origin.y = 0;
 self.view.frame = newFrame;   
}
```

Usually I animate this with 0.33 seconds duration.

Comment: Wait, so where do i put - (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;           and where do i put the stuff changing the frames origin?

Comment: I updated my answer to make it more clear.  Make sure your textFields have your viewController set as the delegate.  Then implement the delegate methods I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

The solution requires quite a bit of code, but here's the general idea of what you need:

You will need to add the text fields (and everything else for consistency) to a scrollView.

You need to setup the scroll view to have vertical scrolling space only, but set the `scrollEnabled` to false so that the user can't scroll it manually.

Then you need to listen to `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and manually scroll it up/down as required.

Comment: what do you mean listen to UIKeyboardWillShowNotification?

Comment: It means knowing when the keyboard will appear and disappear